# What material should I use as spacers to attach these blinds to the window jambs?

Tags: windows, blinds, window-frame

I realized after attempting to install these blinds that they're for windows without a sash. They are intended to be attached to either the glass (with tape) or screwed into the window rails. However, I want to make them work. I'd like to attach them to the jambs so that I can still open and close the window when needed, but the blinds needed to be cut to be narrower to fit within the frame. What material can I use to attach the plastic portion to the jamb? I intend to screw it in, but I'm not sure what I should use. Would wood be best? Or PLA? or maybe cardboard?

These are top-down, bottom up shades from Ikea - Hornvallmo

[image: Window with blind]

[image: Bottom of window]

[image: Plastic part and cardboard]

[image: Top of window]

Thank you!

[image: hornvallmo ikea screws]

Comment: Alternately, if you could find a plastic block in an off-white color similar to the...brackets?...you could use that as a spacer and not really have to deal with matching staining.  Looks like the brackets are simply intended to be stick-on?  I don't see any screw holes.

Comment: @Huesmann They can either be stuck on (for glass) or screwed in. The little screw holes are essentially optional perforations

Answer (score 0):

Just about anything rigid will do as a simple spacer. It's really a matter of design/decoration preference.

I'd probably go with some nylon bushings. They're inconspicuous and look integral. They can be found in many sizes at your local hardware store and match color fairly well. You can cut them with a miter saw or hacksaw. A 3/16" inner diameter would probably be appropriate.

I'd also drill the mounting holes a bit larger so you can use #10 or #12 screws for better rigidity. They should penetrate the jamb at least 3/4" and be piloted slightly smaller than the screw shank.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://yachtgurus.us/products/nylon-trailer-spring-bushing-trailer-parts?variant=41249120813101)</sub>